# p value in SPSS correspondence analysis

Tags: spss, p-value, correspondence-analysis

When I did a correspondence analysis to  two ordinal data variables with each having six categories I get this table from SPSS.

[image]

What does this p value indicate? Does this mean there is no association between the two variables at 5% significance level?

But when I did cross tabulation for these two variables it had a p value of 0.002 indicating that the two variables are associated.

Doesn't correspondence analysis indicate if two variables are associated, then which row is associated with which column? So why does cross tabulation indicate they are associated and correspondence analysis gives that they are not?

What does the p-value in this SPSS output in correspondence analysis mean?

Comment: SPSS correspondence analysis tests for significance of of eigenvalues according to how it is described in the SPSS Algorithms document (read it). It suggests to decide on the better dimensionality of your map. Ultimately, however, it is you who decides how many dimensions to use.

Comment: Note that CA is a mapping / dimensionality reduction techique for nominal categorical data. It is not quite appropriate if you want make sense of _ordinal_ data. Use categorical PCA by optimal scaling (CATPCA) instead then.

Comment: @ttnphns, why not turn that into an answer. This seems at least as much a statistical understanding of CA issue as it is a how to use SPSS issue. I'm inclined to think this should be considered on topic here.

Comment: In general, if you activate a pivot table by double clicking on it and right click on a column header, you can choose "What's This" from the context menu and get a short description of what the statistic means.